# SVN - Why I see ignored files with 'status' command?

Tags: svn

I try to ignore a complete folder in a SVN repository.

I typed :

```
$ svn propset svn:ignore tmp .
```

The command works :

```
$ svn propget svn:ignore .
tmp
```

Now, I touch a dummy file in the tmp folder

```
$ touch tmp/foo.bar
```

Is that normal that this file is displayed with status command ?

```
$ svn status
M      .
?      tmp/foo.bar
```

Regards

edit : some informations

```
svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
Debian wheezy 64b
```

My SVN is "local", without any configuration modification.

Comment: Weird, it doesn't do this on my end - just tried it out with SVN 1.8 on Linux and Windows.

Comment: @zb226 So you confirm that is an "unwanted feature". I never used svn and I didn't know if it was a bug or a normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure that you already have `svn add`ed and `svn commit`ted the `tmp` folder to your repository, before you tried to ignore it - this is not how ignoring works in SVN. This is the only way I could reproduce the output you describe. To resolve, first revert the property changes, then `svn del` the `tmp` folder again (note that this will delete the files in the folder), commit that change and then repeat the procedure you described above.

Comment: Exact ! You're true, I already have commited the folder, I forgot to specify it, sorry. Your solution works perfectly.